# Why does the Combine Publisher protocol have receive<S> and subscribe<S> with identical constraints?

Tags: swift, combine

Here's the `Publisher` protocol:

```
public protocol Publisher {
  associatedtype Output
  associatedtype Failure: Error

  func receive<S>(subscriber: S) 
    where S: Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input
}
```

The `receive(subscriber:)` function requirement is meant to attach a subscriber to the publisher. However, in a protocol extension, there's a very similar function:

```
extension Publisher {
  public func subscribe<S>(_ subscriber: S) 
    where S: Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input
}
```

Both `receive(subscriber:)` and `subscribe(_:)` have identical constraints on the functions. I'm wondering why there's a need for both

Comment: This might help. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorscustom.html

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the `subscribe` method in a disassembler, you'll find that it can potentially do a bunch of debug/diagnostic work. It refers to private types called `Combine.SubscriberTap` and `Combine.DebugHook`.

The Combine framework's architecture is quite “thin”, really. The `receive(subscriber:)` method creates a direct connection between a `Publisher` and a `Subscriber`. After this connection is established, these objects can talk to each other without calling through any Combine code. (Compare this with the SwiftUI architecture, where you create `View` objects but SwiftUI transforms them into completely different objects like `UIView`s under the hood.)

Apple encourages you to use the `subscribe(_:)` method instead of calling `receive(subscriber:)`. This gives the Combine framework a chance to connect your publisher and subscriber indirectly, routing their communication through its own debug hooks.